# Scene in "12 Strong" on women's education in Afghanistan based on what?

Tags: historical-accuracy, 12-strong

In the movie "12 Strong" (2018) there is a scene in which a Taliban imam in Afghanistan publicly executes a woman for educating her children and after he does so, he raises up a book and says that it is written that no girl over the age of 8 shall be educated.

However, from what little I know of the Koran there is no such precept. So, what is this scene based on? Is there a rule in the Koran that forbids the education of women?

Some [articles I have read](https://www.theguardian.com/world/shortcuts/2014/dec/21/taliban-alarmingly-efficient-war-education-peshawar-attack) seem to suggest that the Taliban do not actually ban women from reading the Koran, only from attending schools that have curriculum content with "western decadence". So, is that the basic idea, it is fine for them to read, only they can read the Koran and nothing else?

Comment: https://politics.stackexchange.com/ or https://islam.stackexchange.com/ perhaps.